# How does a ring oscillator get voltage?

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, oscillator

I am reading a book about digital design, and I came across the ring oscillator:

[image]

What I do not understand is where does it get a voltage from if there is no input? How can it then oscillate?

Comment: That isn't a complete schematic. The supply connections aren't shown, is all.

Answer (score 7):

All logic circuits need power supplies to work. They don't work without power.

Logic circuits may be drawn without power input for simplicity, like in this case.

Comment: Thank you, could you please indicate where the power supply in the circuit is?

Comment: There is none because it is not drawn. Each inverter might be separate or these might be all inverters in a same chip. Therefore, drawing supply pins to these inverters or a power supply to them is irrelevant.

Comment: But is it the power that controls the inverters that also give power to the ring?

Comment: @user394334 I don't understand your question. Everything needs power to work. Inverters, AND gates, OR gates, and circuits that consists of them. This is no exception, and the inverters are just connected as a ring oscillator. Logic circuits do not take power from their inputs, but they need power to work, and their output voltage and current come from the power supply. Power does not control the inverters, they just need power to function at all.

Comment: What I struggle with is understanding how it starts when there is no input. The power connected to the inverters is as I understand not a part of the ring?

Comment: But there is input. Each inverter takes input from output of another inverter. The power is just power for the inverters. If you are confused, likely your book will first explain what happens when there is no ring of inverters but just one inverter which connects output to input.

Comment: Thank you. No my book abstracts the construction of inverters away. But I see on wikipedia that the output of an inverter gets connected to a power source or ground? So I guess that explains how the oscilliation starts?

Comment: @user394334 All logic gates use power. When we draw logic gate diagrams we do not have to draw the power, because everyone knows there is power and there is no reason to draw it. The power is not something that the diagram is supposed to explain. (However, some diagrams do explain logic gate power, and in those diagrams, the power is drawn. If the reader needs to know where the power is connected, then the diagram must show it)

Answer (score 2):

Logic gates are voltage controlled complementary (CMOS) switches between Vdd and Vss. If you have an odd number of inverters in a loop you have negative feedback towards the input threshold as the output is inverted from the input. The input and internal capacitance reacts with the driving low impedance to create the propagation delay and overall cycle time.

It does not take intrinsic noise to start oscillations in RING osc. But some other bipolar Op Amp types, this is necessary, although it doesn't hurt.

Normally when DC Power is applied the intrinsic capacitance in every PN junction at 0V is maximum and FETs also have an input Ciss and output Coss capacitance that is the initial condition. This biases the input Pch to activate and pull the output high which starts a low RdsOn output state that goes to Vdd and when it passes the input threshold then the input activates the Nch to drive the output low in a repeating cycle with the chain of inverters.

One requirement for these "RING" Oscillators to work is the gain at high frequency cycle time must be sufficient to be faster than the propagation time to oscillate at the threshold voltage with a very small output swing at unity gain frequency. So more stages are used to provide full swing and thus derive the net contribution from each equal inverter.

Otherwise it might only be a steady DC self-biased at the input threshold or with a very small output triangular swing.  So a certain number of inverters is needed for different RdsOn*Ciss=Tau differences in each  product family are required if you want to achieve full scale swing on the output or a sufficiently low frequency that you can measure.

Comment: Thank you, are you saying in the end of your first section that there is not an equilibrium in the circuit and that is what starts the oscillation?

Comment: Yes. The initial conditions start the oscillation. Towards steady state Q=Ciss Vdd/2.  The 0V input charge voltage and output inverted voltage starts the oscillation. The 1st pulse is longer as it has to travel from 0 to Vdd/2 whereas after this the toggled swings can be  smaller according to the exponential curve or RdsOn*Ciss which are not exactly constant. But since RdsOn is typically very low <= 66 Ohms @ 5V for 75HCxxx as well as Ciss, it starts very fast,  meaning it is low Q (quality factor for frequency staiblity)

Answer (score 1):

Like most oscillators, oscillation will start from intrinsic noise or disturbances in the circuitry.

At startup the logic gates will be biased into their linear region. If the loop gain is greater than unity any noise in the circuit (eg thermal noise) will be amplified and will get larger every pass around the loop.

Eventually the amplitude will build up to the point that saturation occurs. When that happens the amplitude stabilizes. In a circuit like this it will be when the signal is almost equal to the supply rails.

They can be difficult to simulate because of the lack of noise and may require an intentional pulse to kickstart operation.

Comment: Most oscillators start from and initial charge voltage and a bias current. Noise-free simulations work everytime this way.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - I don't know about 'most' but in many cases, yes, oscillations can also be started by the power-on disturbance.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Lets assume X = low, then Y = high, Z = low. If Z is low, X should be high. This seems to be a contradiction to our assumption, but it is not. There is a gate delay for each inverter of the ring, so if X was low, it goes high three gate delays later. Three gate delays is half of the oscillation period. The frequency is therefore 1 / (6 * gate delay).

You may use 5 or 7 or 9 inverters in the ring oscillator, but not 2, 4, 6 or 8. It will oscillate with an odd number of inverters but not with an even number.

Answer (score -7):

It doesn't by itself.You need to put a trigger pulse then remove the trigger pulse in order to have oscillation.

Comment: Most oscillators start operation from intrinsic noise.

Comment: @KevinWhite I have measured noise with my oscilloscope and it is less than 1mV.1mV is so little it won't start any oscillation.

Comment: This answer is wrong. CMOS ring oscillators do start without any trigger.

Comment: No input is necessary to start up a ring oscillator, outside of a simulation anyway. A combination of noise, slight differences between the transistors in the gates, and sometimes intentionally designed-in asymmetry will ensure that the oscillator starts.

Comment: If this circuit were stuck at its metastable operating point,  1 mV would be plenty to knock it into oscillation. Unless it were built with absurdly low gain inverters.